# error with updatepanel and accordion

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a `accordion control(using jQuery)` on the page.  When I insert the contents of my page into an `updatepanel`, the accordion stops working.  If I remove the `updatepanel`, it starts working.

Why?
How can i fix this error?
Do i have to re-instantiate the accordion script/plugin, If yes then how?

```
  <script src="Scripts/ddaccordion.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   ddaccordion.init({
        headerclass: "silverheader", //Shared CSS class name of headers group
        contentclass: "submenu", //Shared CSS class name of contents group
        revealtype: "mouseover", //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the header? Valid value: "click", "clickgo", or "mouseover"
        mouseoverdelay: 200, //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds before header expands onMouseover
        collapseprev: true, //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false
        defaultexpanded: [0], //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc] [] denotes no content
        onemustopen: true, //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)
        animatedefault: false, //Should contents open by default be animated into view?
        persiststate: true, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
        toggleclass: ["", "selected"], //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]
        togglehtml: ["", "", ""], //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)
        animatespeed: "fast", //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"
        oninit: function(headers, expandedindices) { //custom code to run when headers have initalized
            //do nothing
        },
        onopenclose: function(header, index, state, isuseractivated) { //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
            //do nothing
        }
    })
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <div class="applemenu">
        <div class="silverheader"><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Dynamic Drive</a></div>
        <div class="submenu">
            Some random content here<br />
       </div>
       <div class="silverheader"><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/" >CSS Examples</a></div>
       <div class="submenu">
            Some random content here<br />
       </div>
       <div class="silverheader"><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></div>
       <div class="submenu">
            Some random content here<br />
       </div>
       <div class="silverheader"><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></div>
       <div class="submenu">
           Some random content here<br />
          <img src="http://i27.tinypic.com/sy7295.gif" />
       </div>
       <div class="silverheader"><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></div>
       <div class="submenu">
           Some random content here<br />
       </div>       
     </div>    
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You'll get far more responses by just posting the relevant bits of your code, rather than dumping the whole script. Make it easy for us to help you!

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan I edited my question

Answer (score 3):

Use `pageLoad`, it gets called on all partial postbacks:

[$(document).ready() and pageLoad() are not the same!](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad()
    {
       ddaccordion.init({
            headerclass: "silverheader", //Shared CSS class name of headers group
            contentclass: "submenu", //Shared CSS class name of contents group
            revealtype: "mouseover", //Reveal content when user clicks or onmouseover the header? Valid value: "click", "clickgo", or "mouseover"
            mouseoverdelay: 200, //if revealtype="mouseover", set delay in milliseconds before header expands onMouseover
            collapseprev: true, //Collapse previous content (so only one open at any time)? true/false
            defaultexpanded: [0], //index of content(s) open by default [index1, index2, etc] [] denotes no content
            onemustopen: true, //Specify whether at least one header should be open always (so never all headers closed)
            animatedefault: false, //Should contents open by default be animated into view?
            persiststate: true, //persist state of opened contents within browser session?
            toggleclass: ["", "selected"], //Two CSS classes to be applied to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively ["class1", "class2"]
            togglehtml: ["", "", ""], //Additional HTML added to the header when it's collapsed and expanded, respectively  ["position", "html1", "html2"] (see docs)
            animatespeed: "fast", //speed of animation: integer in milliseconds (ie: 200), or keywords "fast", "normal", or "slow"
            oninit: function(headers, expandedindices) { //custom code to run when headers have initalized
                //do nothing
            },
            onopenclose: function(header, index, state, isuseractivated) { //custom code to run whenever a header is opened or closed
                //do nothing
            }
        })
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: accordion does not even load ...if i use your code ...alas :(

Comment: now the page does not load...it starts loading ...and refreshes..and that's it :(

Answer (score 1):

if all content is in update panel than just put your script in update panel and it will start working.

Answer (score 0):

Since the entire content/definition of your accordion is inside your update panel, you will have to re-init it every time the update panel updates because you're essentailly getting a 'fresh' copy of the accordion and any events tied to it are gone.

We've had this problem too (with differnet controls) and our solution is to put the bare minimum we have to inside the update panel, like hidden buttons, and then code the accordion to 'push' those buttons so the update panel does its thing without hosing the accordion.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but it is still unsolved.

So, here you have two issues:

The **first**, as pointed out by @rickschott, you need to initialize the plugin after each partial postback (not only the first time) because the plugin is inside an UpdatePanel, so it will stop working after the UpdatePanel is updated.

When you fix that, you encounter a **second** issue: seems that the page gets refreshing all the time, and never loads. This issue could be consider as a bug of ddaccordion jquery plugin. Seems it is not designed to be reset (or to destroy and recreate without loading the page from scratch). I did a workaround but you may have to test it:

- Open `ddaccordion.js` and find `init:function(config)` in it.
- Remove this four lines:

```js
document.write('<style type="text/css">\n')
document.write('.'+config.contentclass+'{display: none}\n') //generate CSS to hide contents
document.write('a.hiddenajaxlink{display: none}\n') //CSS class to hide ajax link
document.write('<\/style>')
```

- Now it will work as expected. Remember to add those 2 css classes to your css file:

```css
.submenu { display:none }
a.hiddenajaxlink { display:none }
```

**Important**: It is not recommended to modify 3rd party plugins because every time you update your plugin, you may loose your changes. But it seems that ddaccordion is no longer maintained by its authors, so maybe this could be a good solution, so I hope it helps someone else.